Variable substitution of a PDE containing the Laplace operator in spherical coordinates
The problem in the textbook:
The initial oscillation region of a uniform gas is a sphere with a radius of R0. As an ideal model, it is assumed that all gas mass points have an initial velocity of zero. The initial density of the gas inside the sphere is u0 (a constant), and the density outside the sphere is zero. Determine the density at any point M.
Formulate the initial value problem of the PDE based on the problem description:
There is a three-dimensional wave equation in spherical coordinates, with the initial value problem as follows:
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}u_{t t}-a^2 \nabla^2 u=0 \\ \left.u\right|_{t=0}= \begin{cases}u_0, & R<R_0 \\ 0, & R \geqslant R_0\end{cases} \\ \left.u_t\right|_{t=0}=0\end{array}\right.$
This PDE cannot be solved directly using DSolve.
Clear["Global`*"];

initCond = {u[r, 0] == 
    Piecewise[{{u0, r < R0}, {0, r >= R0}}], (D[u[r, t], t] /. 
      t -> 0) == 0};

lap = Laplacian[u[r, t], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"];

waveEq = D[u[r, t], {t, 2}] - a^2*lap == 0;
sol1 = DSolve[{waveEq, initCond}, u[r, t], {r, t}]
sol1 = Assuming[a > 0 && t >= 0 && R0 > 0 && u0 > 0, 
  FullSimplify[sol1]]

According to the method in the textbook, due to spherical symmetry, in the expression of the Laplace operator in spherical coordinates, two partial derivative terms can be simplified into one partial derivative term.
$\nabla^2 u=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial R^2}+\frac{2}{R} \frac{\partial u}{\partial R}=\frac{1}{R} \frac{\partial^2(R u)}{\partial R^2}$   (1)
Then, a variable substitution ($v=R u$) can be applied to simplify the PDE, after which the equation can be solved to obtain the result.
Substituting into the equation, we obtain:
$v_{t t}-a^2 v_{R R}=0$  (2)
General solution of the equation: From
$v(R, t)=f_1(R+a t)+f_2(R-a t)$ (3)
we get
$u(R, t)=\frac{1}{R}\left[f_1(R+a t)+f_2(R-a t)\right]$  (4)
Determining the functional forms of f1 and f2: Substituting equations into the initial conditions, we have:
$\left.u\right|_{t=0}=\frac{1}{R}\left[f_1(R)+f_2(R)\right]= \begin{cases}u_0, & R<R_0 \\ 0, & R \geqslant R_0\end{cases}$  (5)
$\left.u_t\right|_{t=0}=\frac{1}{R}\left[a f_1^{\prime}(R)-a f_2^{\prime}(R)\right]=0$   (6)
By multiplying both sides of equation (6) by R/a and integrating with respect to R, we get (the integration constant is 2C):
$f_1(R)-f_2(R)=2 C$ (7)
Combining equations, we have:
$f_1(R)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} R u_0+C, & R<R_0 \\ C, & R>R_0\end{cases}$  (8)
$f_2(R)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} R u_0-C, & R<R_0 \\ -C & R>R_0\end{cases}$  (9)
1.When the point M is located outside the sphere
$R+a t>R_0, f_1(R+a t)=C$
while R−at can take different values, i.e.,
$\begin{aligned} u(R, t) & =\frac{1}{R}\left[f_1(R+a t)+f_2(R-a t)\right] \\ & = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{R}\left[C+\frac{1}{2}(R-a t) u_0-C\right]=\frac{R-a t}{2 R} u_0, & R-a t<R_0 \\ \frac{1}{R}[C-C]=0, & R-a t>R_0\end{cases} \end{aligned}$  (10)
Clear["Global`*"]; 
lap = Laplacian[u[r, t], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"];

waveEq = D[u[r, t], {t, 2}] - a^2*lap == 0;
initCond = {u[r, 0] == 
    Piecewise[{{u0, 0 <= r < R0}, {0, r >= R0}}], (D[u[r, t], t] /. 
      t -> 0) == 0};

waveEq = Block[{u}, u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r; waveEq] // FullSimplify;
initCond = 
  Block[{u}, u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r; initCond] // FullSimplify;


sol2 = DSolve[{waveEq, initCond}, v[r, t], {r, t}]


sol2Simplified = 
 Assuming[a > 0 && t >= 0 && R0 > 0 && r >= R0, FullSimplify[sol2]]

u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r

u[r, t] /. sol2Simplified[[1]] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify

Solution:
$\begin{cases}\frac{(r-a t) u 0}{2 r} & a t \leq r \& \& R0+a t>r \\ 0 & \text { True }\end{cases}$  (11)
It is consistent with the solution (10) obtained in the textbook.
2. When the point M is located inside the sphere
both R±at can be greater than or less than R0. Therefore:
$\begin{aligned} u(R, t) & =\frac{1}{R}\left[f_1(R+a t)+f_2(R-a t)\right] \\ & = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{R}\left[\frac{1}{2}(R+a t) u_0+C+\frac{1}{2}(R-a t) u_0-C=u_0,\right. & R-a t<R+a t<R_0 \\ \frac{1}{R}\left[C+\frac{1}{2}(R-a t) u_0-C\right]=\frac{R-a t}{2 R} u_0, & R-a t<R_0<R+a t \\ \frac{1}{R}[C-C]=0 & R_0<R-a t<R+a t\end{cases} \end{aligned}$  (12)
However, the results obtained using MMA programming are relatively chaotic, and it is unclear where the problem lies.
Clear["Global`*"]; 

lap = Laplacian[u[r, t], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"];

waveEq = D[u[r, t], {t, 2}] - a^2*lap == 0;
initCond = {u[r, 0] == 
    Piecewise[{{u0, 0 <= r < R0}, {0, r >= R0}}], (D[u[r, t], t] /. 
      t -> 0) == 0};

waveEq = Block[{u}, u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r; waveEq] // FullSimplify;
initCond = 
  Block[{u}, u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r; initCond] // FullSimplify;


sol2 = DSolve[{waveEq, initCond}, v[r, t], {r, t}]


sol2Simplified = 
 Assuming[a > 0 && t >= 0 && R0 > 0 && 0 <= r < R0, FullSimplify[sol2]]

u[r_, t_] := v[r, t]/r

u[r, t] /. sol2Simplified[[1]] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify

Solution:
$\left[\begin{array}{ll}u 0 & r+a t<R 0 \& \& a t \leq r \\ \frac{(r+a t) u0}{2 r} & r+a t<R0 \\ \frac{(r-a t) u0}{2 r} & a t \leq r \\ 0 & \text { True }\end{array}\right.$ (13)
This is very different from the result (12) in the textbook, and the value range of r is chaotic and cannot be explained.
My questions are:

Is it possible to solve the initial value problem of this PDE using MMA without performing variable substitution? Perhaps there are some issues I overlooked in my code.

Can the collection of partial derivatives in Equation (1), be automatically implemented in MMA? This would allow us to observe the variable substitution directly.

Why is the result (13) obtained by MMA very different from the result (12) in the textbook, and why is the value range of r chaotic and inexplicable?


In summary, what method can be used to fully leverage the advantages of MMA and minimize manual calculations?

Background Info
The textbook I'm refering to is: Wang Dexin, Mathematical Methods in Physics (4th Edition), Science Press, 2016, ISBN: 978-7-03-046471-2. The exercise can be found on pp. 232, question 10.2.1, and the detailed solution is on pp. 412–413. The detailed solution to question 10.2.1 can also be found on pp. 87–88 of this link, and it is the same as the one in the textbook. Both of the reference are in Chinese, but you can at least read the formula.

"Can the collection of partial derivatives in Equation (1), be automatically implemented in MMA? This would allow us to observe the variable substitution directly." Do you mean you're expecting something similar to Factor for polynomials, or you're looking for DChange/DSolveChangeVariables?

BTW, the solution given by your last code sample is not right, try e.g. Piecewise[{{u0, r + a*t < R0}, {((r - a*t)*u0)/(2*r), R0 + a*t > r}},    0] /. {a -> 1, R0 -> 1, t -> 2, r -> 0} This is related to certain long-standing bug of DSolve, I guess. (May be related to Piecewise, just search e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbugs%5D+dsolve+piecewise )


Yes, I'm expecting something similar to Factor for polynomials. It is possible to combine the two partial derivative terms into one, similar to completing the total differential, or is there a built-in function or code that can achieve a process similar to the inverse of the chain rule? @xzczd♦



Regarding your second comment, I have edited my question. The solution under the first condition (point M outside the sphere) is consistent with the textbook, but the solution under the second condition (point M inside the sphere) is not consistent with the textbook. I checked the link you provided, and it seems that this bug has been fixed in the new version of MMA. I am wondering if there is an error in my code. @xzczd♦



Sadly, for now there's no built-in or package for "inverse of the chain rule" AFAIK. 2. So far I haven't found mistake in your code. Though the bug mentioned here is fixed, from the link we can see there still exists a number of issues related to discontinuity handling of DSolve, so I won't be surprised if there exists a related issue somewhere. But anyway, this is merely my guess.


It seems DSolve[{Derivative[0,2][v][r,t]-a^2 Derivative[2,0][v][r,t]==0,v[r,0]==r*u0*HeavisideTheta[R0-r],Derivative[0,1][v][r,0]==0},v[r,t],{r,t}] gives a correct solution for the interior region.

The current (12) is still incorrect. As it is currently written, for any sufficiently large $t$, $R−at<R_0<R+at$ is always satisfied, so the solution will always be $-\infty$ for $u>0$ when $t$ is large enough at $R=0$.

I've figured out what's wrong with the analysis and found the correct solution. (Verified with numeric solution. ) Before posting an answer, I'd like to confirm: does the textbook really give (10) and (12) as the solution? Or it simply gives some hint and you've completed the solution by yourself? If the former, can you add the reference?

@yarchik  It seems to be different from the answer in the textbook: $\left{\left{v[r, t] \rightarrow\left{\begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(r+\sqrt{a^2} t\right) \text { u } 0 \text { HeavisideTheta }\left[-r+R0-\sqrt{a^2} t\right]+\left(r-\sqrt{a^2} t\right) \text { u } 0 \text { HeavisideTheta }\left[-r+R0+\sqrt{a^2} t\right]\right) \quad t \geq 0 \ \text { Indeterminate } \ \text { True }\end{array}\right}\right.\right.$

@xzczd♦ The textbook is: Wang Dexin, Mathematical Methods in Physics (4th Edition), Science Press, 2016, ISBN: 978-7-03-046471-2. The exercise can be found on pp. 232, question 10.2.1, and the detailed solution is on pp. 412–413. The solution steps I provided are exactly as given in the textbook, without any modifications. However, I cannot rule out the possibility of errors in the textbook’s exercise solutions, as it is an exercise. If it were an example, the likelihood of errors would be relatively much smaller.

@xzczd♦ The detailed solution to question 10.2.1 can also be found on pp. 87–88 of this link, and it is the same as the one in the textbook: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/536891496

Extend my comments to an answer.


Is it possible to solve the initial value problem of this PDE using MMA without performing variable substitution? Perhaps there are some issues I overlooked in my code.


I think the first paragraph of this answer of mine still applies here.


Can the collection of partial derivatives in Equation (1), be automatically implemented in MMA? This would allow us to observe the variable substitution directly.


Sadly, for now there's no built-in or package for "inverse of the chain rule", "Factor for derivative", etc. AFAIK. (BTW, though I can't find that post for the moment, I roughly remember that user21 once mentioned it's rather hard to implement something like that in a comment under my answer. )


Why is the result (13) obtained by MMA very different from the result (12) in the textbook, and why is the value range of r chaotic and inexplicable?


It's because the DSolve solution and text book solution are both wrong.
The key point is, since we've introduced the change of variable $v=ru$, an additional boundary condition $\left.v\right|_{r=0}=0$ is imposed. We must take this into account in some way, no matter what method we're using. This is missing in the textbook solution and DSolve solution in the question, ruining both of them.
The following is the fixed code. I've used DChange for variable changing.
Clear[u, r, t, a];

{eq, ic} = 
  With[{u = u[r, t]}, 
       {D[u, {t, 2}] - a^2 Laplacian[u, {r, th, phi}, "Spherical"] == 0,
       {u == Piecewise[{{u0, r < R0}, {0, r >= R0}}], 
        D[u, t] == 0} /. t -> 0}];
(* Definition of DChange isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
newsys = {DChange[{eq, ic}, u[r, t] == v[r, t]/r] // Simplify[#, r > 0] &, 
          v[0, t] == 0}

solref = FullSimplify[1/r DSolveValue[newsys, v[r, t], {r, t}], 
                      {r >= 0, R0 > 0, a > 0, t > 0}]
(* Takes about 14 seconds on my laptop. *)


Then let's compare it with numeric solution for validation. The discontinuous initial condition is a bit challenging for numeric solving even if we set $\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right|_{r=0}=0$ for stablization, but luckily the method found in this post applies:
mol[n_, o_ : "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

para = # /. {a -> 1, R0 -> 2, u0 -> 1} &;

nsys = {eq, ic} // para;

bc0 = D[u[r, t], r] == 0 /. r -> 0;

R = 10; tend = 7; tpoints = 400;

nsol = NDSolveValue[{nsys, bc0}, u, {t, 0, tend}, {r, 0, R}, 
     Method -> 
      Union[mol[600, 4], 
            {Method -> {"FixedStep", 
              Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", 
                         "Coefficients" -> 
                           "ImplicitRungeKuttaRadauIACoefficients"}}}],
      StartingStepSize -> {Automatic, tend/tpoints}] // 
    Quiet; // AbsoluteTiming

Manipulate[
   Plot[{#, nsol[r, t]} // para // Evaluate, {r, 0, R}, 
    PlotRange -> 1.1 para[u0], PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}], {t, 0, 
    tend}] &@solref


As we can see, the symbolic solution and numeric solution agree well.
Remark

I have used DChange instead of DSolveChangeVariables because the latter is too fragile at least for now.

I haven't set boundary condition at the outer boundary, but given the solution of wave equation is localized, this should not be too big a problem as long as there's no interaction between boundary and solution. But do remember that, for PDE with non-localized solution e.g. heat equation, the missing of boundary condition can be a severe problem, see this post for more info. And, if the solution of wave equation spreads to the outer boundary, techniques like perfectly matched layer (PML) or absorbing boundary condition (ABC) will be necessary. (Related examples can be found in the document and this site. )



Thank you for your explanation. I have understood part of the content, but I still need to study the initial conditions further.

@lotus2019 Honestly speaking, the i.c. has surprised me, too :) . I've played with PDE for so many years, but I've never noticed that discontinuous yet finite i.c. can evolve to infinite (though only at the origin, and only at a single time) for spherical symmetric wave equation.

As demonstrated, the substitution yields a radial 1-d wave equation, that can be solved without problems
DSolveValue[
   {D[v[r, t], t, t] - D[v[r, t], r, r] == 0, 
    v[r, 0] == r Boole[-1 < r < 1], 
    Derivative[0, 1][v][r, 0] == 0}, 
    v[r, t], {r, t}]

$$v[r,t]=\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} ((r-t) \text{Boole}[-1<r-t<1]+(r+t) \text{Boole}[-1<r+t<1]) & t\geq 0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$
yielding the 3d wave
 u[r_, t_] = (Piecewise[{{1/2 (1 - t/r), -1 < r - t < 1}, {0, True}}] +
              Piecewise[{{1/2 (1 + t/r), -1 < r + t < 1}, {0, True}}])

A state evolution confirms the wave front velocity of 1
 Manipulate[
    RevolutionPlot3D[u[r, t], {r, 0, 3 t}, Exclusions -> None], 
    {{t, 1}, 0.001, 6}]


Confirmation
 D[u[r, t], t, t] - 1/r^2 D[(r^2 D[u[r, t], r]), r] // Expand

$$-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{t}{r^3} & -1<r+t<1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{t}{r^3} & -1<r-t<1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\frac{2 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{t}{2 r^2} & -1<r-t<1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{r}-\frac{2 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{t}{2 r^2} & -1<r+t<1 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{r}$$
%//Simplify
0

Addendum:
The 1-d wave equation has the form $$(\partial_t +\partial_x) \ (\partial_t-\partial_x) \  u \ = \ 0,$$ so it obvious, that any distribution $$u(x,t)=a(x+t) + b(x-t)$$ is a solution. given $$u(0,x) =U(x) = a(0,x)+b(0,x), $$
$$\partial_t u(0,x)=V(x) = \partial_t a(0,x) -\partial_t b(0,x)$$ are fixed.
By geometric coincidence, the 3D the solution is the 1D solution evolving on spheres $$u_{3d}= r^{-1} u(t,r)$$ and there is no spatial wave dispersion into the inner of the light, contrary to 2d.
This is the reason why in 4D space-time we can see and hear 1-1 whatever is emitted from a point source, because the signal of a distributional $\delta(\vec x)\ \delta(t)$ source is concentrated on the light/sound cone $c^2 t^2-\vec x^2 =0 $. This is true even for discontinuous signals of finite total energy.

I need to study this problem further. Thank you for your answer.
